# C# save time for later checks on a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datetime, save

as always i need your help!

Inside a foreach of a string array (containing cryptocurrency ticker names like "XRP", "SC", "XMR" and so on) i have a statement where i need to test if the value of a decimal is above 100. If this is true then i need to save the current coin and the current time where the value was above 100 but only if that happened one time in the last hour. I then need to keep in the list only the last 24 hour where the threshold has been excedeed and count how many elements the list has inside.

So thinking about this in a logical way it means having something using my coin string as index key that can return the count of the values inside that list for the last 24hours.

For example
It's 18-09-2017 at 17:00 o'clock

```
Count  Coin   Time
[1]    XRP    17-09-2017 19:32:40
[2]    XRP    18-09-2017 03:11:29
[3]    XRP    18-09-2017 11:09:38
[4]    XRP    18-09-2017 16:34:42

[1]    SC     17-09-2017 17:35:24
[2]    SC     17-09-2017 23:43:53
[3]    SC     18-09-2017 07:32:44
[4]    SC     18-09-2017 15:43:22
```

and so on..

When the time is 23:00:00 i need the first value of all the lists that had their first call more than 24 hours ago to get removed from the list like so:

```
Count  Coin   Time
[1]    XRP    18-09-2017 03:11:29
[2]    XRP    18-09-2017 11:09:38
[3]    XRP    18-09-2017 16:34:42

[1]    SC     17-09-2017 23:43:53
[2]    SC     18-09-2017 07:32:44
[3]    SC     18-09-2017 15:43:22
```

The code i tried to use is this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> CallsDict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();

List<string> Tickers = new List<string>(new string[]{ "XMR", "SC", "MYST", "NEO", "DGB", "LBC", "ETH", "XRP", "LUN", "OMG", "ARK", "LTC", "QTUM", "BCC", "TRIG", "BTS", "LSK", "OK", "XVG", "CFI" });

decimal PercentBuyVolume = 0;

foreach (var coin in Tickers)
    {
        string[] timeFrames = { "oneMin", "thirtyMin", "hour", "day" };
        foreach (var interval in timeFrames)
        {
        var client = new WebClient();

        string URL = ("https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetTicks?marketName=BTC-" + coin + "&tickInterval=" + interval);
        var chiusure = new List<decimal>();
        var BuyVolume = new List<decimal>();
        var prices = client.DownloadString(URL);
        var pricesDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(prices);
        foreach (var data in pricesDeserialized.result)
        {
            chiusure.Add(data.C);
            if (interval == "hour") { BuyVolume.Add(data.BV); }
        }
        int sizeOfArrayClose = chiusure.Count - 1;
        LP = chiusure[sizeOfArrayClose];

        if (interval == "hour")
        {
            decimal LastBuyVolume = MA(sizeOfArrayClose, 24, BuyVolume);
            decimal NowBuyVolume = BuyVolume[sizeOfArrayClose];
            decimal PercentCalc = (NowBuyVolume - LastBuyVolume) / LastBuyVolume * 100;

            PercentBuyVolume = Math.Round(PercentCalc, 2);

if (PercentBuyVolume > 100)
{
    DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine("Coin: " + coin);
    List<DateTime> items;
    if (!CallsDict.TryGetValue(coin, out items))
    {

        CallsDict[coin].Add(DateTime.Now);
    }
    else if (CallsDict[coin][(CallsDict[coin].Count - 1)].AddHours(1) < DateTime.Now)
    {
        if (CallsDict[coin][0].AddDays(1) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            CallsDict[coin].RemoveAt(0);
            Console.WriteLine("Rimosso per vecchiaia, nuova last call: " + CallsDict[coin][0]);
        }
        CallCount = CallsDict[coin].Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Call Count last 24h: " + CallCount);
    }
   }
   }
```

}

I get exception in `CallsDict[coin].Add(DateTime.Now);`everyime PercentBuyVolume is above 100.

What can i do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You probably meant `CallsDict.Add(coin, new List<DateTime>{ DateTime.Now });`

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> CallsDict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();
```

The key is a `string` and the value is a `List<DateTime>`. Before you can add to the `List<DateTime>`, you have to create the list firstly. Therefore, check if the list is created or not:

```
List<DateTime> items;
if (!CallsDict.TryGetValue("SomeKey", out items))
{
    CallsDict.Add("SomeKey", new List<DateTime>());
}
```

Also, if you call look at a line of code and figure out its type just by reading that line, you can use `var` to avoid having to type the whole type like this (also use camel case for locals):

```
var callsDict = new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();
```

Comment: That works! But now i fail all these tests

`  else if (CallsDict[coin][(CallsDict[coin].Count - 1)].AddHours(1) < DateTime.Now)
    {
        if (CallsDict[coin][0].AddDays(1) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            CallsDict[coin].RemoveAt(0);
            Console.WriteLine("Rimosso per vecchiaia, nuova last call: " + CallsDict[coin][0]);
        }
        CallCount = CallsDict[coin].Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Call Count last 24h: " + CallCount);
    }
   } `

Comment: @Revengeic3 Thats a different issue... When you create the list then i think you should add something to it right away because you know what needs to be added to it.